# merging sorted files Java

Tags: java

im implementing external merge sort using Java.

So given a file I split it into smaller ones , then sort the smaller portions and finally merge the sorted (smaller) files.

So , the last step is what im having trouble with.

I have a list of files and I want at each step , take the minimum value of the first rows of each file and then remove that line.

So , it is supposed to be something like this:

```
public static void mergeSortedFiles(List<File> sorted, File output) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter wf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output));
    String curLine = "";
    while(!sorted.isEmpty()) {
        curLine = findMinLine(sorted);
        wf.write(curLine);
    }
}

public static String findMinLine(List<File> sorted) throws IOException {
    List<BufferedReader> brs = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i =0; i<sorted.size() ; i++) {
        brs.add(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sorted.get(i))));
    }
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    for(BufferedReader br : brs) {
        lines.add(br.readLine());
    }
    Collections.sort(lines);
    return lines.get(0);
}
```

Im not sure how to update the files, anyone can help with that?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Why is your first argument a list of `File` objects? Wouldn't it be easier to have two input arguments instead? Something like `mergeSortedFiles(File left, File right, File output)` because you use merge only on two files anyway. This would remove a lot of list handling when you have always exactly two input files anyway.

Comment: @Progman i need to merge all of the sorted files, do you mean that i should merge them 2 files at a time?

Comment: That's what you usually do in "Merge sort". You merge only two inputs instead of N inputs.

Comment: @Progman I'm not sure that's true of a memory-bounded merge using files. I'd be interested to know how Spark collects a sorted RDD for example. Sure, you could do more things in parallel by merging all files by pairs but the implementation would be much trickier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Comparable` wrapper around each file and then place the wrappers in a heap (for example a `PriorityQueue`).

```
public class ComparableFile<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<ComparableFile<T>> {
    private final Deserializer<T> deserializer;
    private final Iterator<String> lines;
    private T buffered;

    public ComparableFile(File file, Deserializer<T> deserializer) {
        this.deserializer = deserializer;
        try {
            this.lines = Files.newBufferedReader(file.toPath()).lines().iterator();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // deal with it differently if you want, I'm just providing a working example
            // and wanted to use the constructor in a lambda function
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ComparableFile<T> that) {
        T mine = peek();
        T theirs = that.peek();

        if (mine == null) return theirs == null ? 0 : -1;
        if (theirs == null) return 1;
        return mine.compareTo(theirs);
    }

    public T pop() {
        T tmp = peek();

        if (tmp != null) {
            buffered = null;
            return tmp;
        }

        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return peek() == null;
    }

    private T peek() {
        if (buffered != null) return buffered;
        if (!lines.hasNext()) return null;
        return buffered = deserializer.deserialize(lines.next());
    }
}
```

Then, you can merge them this way:

```
public class MergeFiles<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private final PriorityQueue<ComparableFile<T>> files;

    public MergeFiles(List<File> files, Deserializer<T> deserializer) {
        this.files = new PriorityQueue<>(files.stream()
                .map(file -> new ComparableFile<>(file, deserializer))
                .filter(comparableFile -> !comparableFile.isEmpty())
                .collect(toList()));
    }

    public Iterator<T> getSortedElements() {
        return new Iterator<T>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return !files.isEmpty();
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {
                if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
                ComparableFile<T> head = files.poll();
                T next = head.pop();
                if (!head.isEmpty()) files.add(head);
                return next;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And here's some code to demonstrate it works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<File> files = Arrays.asList(
            newTempFile(Arrays.asList("hello", "world")),
            newTempFile(Arrays.asList("english", "java", "programming")),
            newTempFile(Arrays.asList("american", "scala", "stackoverflow"))
    );

    Iterator<String> sortedElements = new MergeFiles<>(files, line -> line).getSortedElements();
    while (sortedElements.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(sortedElements.next());
    }
}

private static File newTempFile(List<String> words) throws IOException {
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("sorted-", ".txt");
    Files.write(tempFile.toPath(), words);
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();
    return tempFile;
}
```

Output:

```
american
english
hello
java
programming
scala
stackoverflow
world
```

Comment: isn't just a way to mearge a list of files ? i want to  find the minimum value of the first lines of that list, then write it to the output, delete it from the file and repeat. if you can help with that it would be great.

Comment: Why would you want to delete the value from the file ? You're consuming an input stream, modifying the file at the same time wouldn't exactly be a good idea in the same way that you shouldn't mutate a collection while you're iterating it (unless it explicitly supports it). you can delete the files at the end of the merge or when you have consumed all the lines in the file.

Comment: im not allowed to add more class to this program :-) i want to delete the minimum values so i know when to stop (where all files are deleted) because im not sure how to iterate over the files simultaneously..

Comment: I don't like when assignments add constraints such as "no class". Java is an OOP language, classes are the building blocks of Java code, doesn't it seem like a very arbitrary requirement ? Also, you don't have to delete the values to know when to stop, you just need to know you have consumed all the bytes from the input stream. That's what my code does when I eliminate an empty `ComparableFile` from the heap. My code also addresses your problem of iterating the files simultaneously in the `MergeFiles` class. Feel free to ask more questions if you don't understand some parts of the answer.

Comment: I know that if we add enough comments here they will eventually give us a link to it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161934/discussion-between-dici-and-liad).

Comment: Where should we close the buffered reader created in ComparableFile class. If I close it in the same class, it is giving stream closed error - Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Comment: What is Deserializer supposed to look like?

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is to swap two lines in a text file? You can do it by using a `RandomAccessFile` however this will be horrible slow since everytime when you swap two lines you have to wait for the next IO burst.
So i highly recommend you to use the following code to be able to do the merge sort on the heap:

```
List<String> lines1 = Files.readAllLines(youFile1);
List<String> lines2 = Files.readAllLines(youFile2);
//use merge sort on theese lines
List<String> merged;
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(yourOutputFile); 
for(String str: merged) {
    writer.write(str + System.lineSeparator());
}
writer.close();
```

Comment: while merging the sorted files i want to delete rows from them (the minimum row of the files)

Comment: Yes but in that case u want to delete a row from one file and put it into another one which is pretty much the same. And as i said it is possible using RandomAccessFile, but you will have to rewrite the file from the position of the minimal line.

Comment: I just editied the code so that it actually applies ot merging two files

Comment: Hm, i need to merge more then two files

Comment: Just write a method for this purpose which takes two files to merge as parameter and returns the merged file?

Answer (score 0):

The standard merge technique between a fixed number of files (say, 2) is :

- have a variable for the value of the ordering key of the current record of each file (for java, make that variable Comparable).
- start the process by reading the first record of each file (and fill in the corresponding variable)
- loop (until end-of-file on both) through a code block that says essentially

if (key_1.compareTo(key_2) == 0) { process both files ; then read both files}
else if (key_1.compareTo(key_2) == -1) { process file 1 ; then read file 1}
else { process file 2 ; then read file 2}

Note how this code does essentially nothing more than determine the file with the lowest key, and process that.

If your number of files is variable, then your number of key variables is variable too, and "determining the file with the lowest current key" cannot be done as per above.  Instead, have as many current_key_value objects as there are files, and store them all in a TreeSet.  Now, the first element of the TreeSet will be the lowest current key value of all the files and if you make sure that you maintain a link between your key variable and the file number you just process that file (and delete the just processed key value from the TreeSet and read a new record from the processed file and add its key value to the TreeSet).